$\mathbb{P}^{1}$ is a closed subscheme of $\mathbb{P}^{2}$
My question: Let $\Bbbk$ be a field, char $\Bbbk \neq 2, 3$. $C = V_{p}(X_{0}^{2} - X_{1}^{2} - X_{2}^{2}) \subset \mathbb{P}^{2}$.
(1). As scheme, $C \cong \mathbb{P}^{1}$.
(2). Calculate $\dim_{\Bbbk} \Gamma(C, \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^{2}}(1)|_{C})$.
My attempt: (1). As a scheme, $\mathbb{P}^{2}$ has an affine open cover $\cup_{i = 0}^{2} U_{i}$, where $U_{i} = Spec(\Bbbk [\frac{X_{0}}{X_{i}}, \frac{X_{1}}{X_{i}}, \frac{X_{2}}{X_{i}}])$. So we have $C = V(1 - (\frac{X_{1}}{X_{0}})^{2} - (\frac{X_{2}}{X_{0}})^{2}) \cup V((\frac{X_{0}}{X_{1}})^{2} - 1 - (\frac{X_{2}}{X_{1}})^{2}) \cup V((\frac{X_{0}}{X_{2}})^{2} - (\frac{X_{1}}{X_{2}})^{2} - 1)$. However, viewing the intersection of the affine open set with $C$ in this way does not seem sufficient to prove that $C \cong \mathbb{P}^{1}$. Did I make a mistake or do I need a more accurate proof method?
(2). I know there is such a conclusion: if $d \geq 0$, $\Gamma(\mathbb{P}^{k}, \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^{k}}(d)) = Span_{\Bbbk}\{ X_{0}^{i_{0}}X_{1}^{i_{1}}\dots X_{n}^{i_{n}} \}_{i_{0} + \dots + i_{n} = d}$. But I don't know how to apply this conclusion, is there $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^{2}}(1)|_{C} \cong \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^{1}}(1)$?.
Related definitions: $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^{k}}(d)$ is an invertible sheaf on $\mathbb{P}^{k}$, $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^{k}}(d)|_{\mathbb{A}_{i}^{k}} := \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^{k}}\cdot(s_{i} := X_{i}^{d})$ for $i = 0, \dots, k$, where $\mathbb{A}_{i}^{k} = Spec(\Bbbk [\frac{X_{0}}{X_{i}}, \dots, \frac{X_{k}}{X_{i}}])$ is affine open set of $\mathbb{P}^{k}$.
Any hints would be appreciated!
